# Is it possible to have Siri perform a task / action in my App?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, siri

With the release of iOS 5, and more specifically 'Siri', is it possible to have that Application perform an action / task in one of my Apps?

In other words, I have [read here](http://www.mobiledevproonline.com/article/mobile-apps/google-apples-siri-offer-api-options-developers-140825) that the App integrates with Fandango to order movie tickets.

So, how could I register an event / function of my App with Siri so that it performs a task?

For arguments sake, lets pretend my App also sells movie tickets like Fandango .. why do they get to have all of the fun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your linked text [Google+ and Apple's Siri offer API options for developers](http://www.mobiledevproonline.com/article/mobile-apps/google-apples-siri-offer-api-options-developers-140825):

> ...Siri, whose capabilities hinge on its use of links to **non-Siri mobile apps via APIs**. You don't need to tell Siri to open Fandango, for
>   example, you just tell it to buy movie tickets and it takes it from
>   there. When Siri's asked for the best slice of pizza/cup of
>   coffee/manicure in a user's area, it races through resources such as
>   Yahoo! and Yelp for answers.

The text above is confusing, it sounds like some mobile apps have an Apple blessed non public API that Siri is using. It should say instead "whose capabilities hinge on its use of links to **non mobile apps via APIs**".

Siri uses Yelp behind scenes to offer an equivalent functionality as the Fandango app, but it doesn't integrate with 3rd party apps. So far there is no mention of an API for Siri.